# Best alternative to overlapping subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I have a `UIView` containing a login form, however when the user is already logged in, I want to show a logout button instead of the form.

My current approach is creating a subview for both the login form and the login button, overlapping each other in Interface Builder.

I would then only show one of the subviews at a time.

Is there a better way of doing this so it is easier to design in Interface Builder, while still using the same `UIViewController`?

If it matters the view is a modal view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tweak your `UIViewController` to actually be a `UITabBarController`, but tweak the tab bar so that it's not visible when the controller is pushed to the screen:

`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

This should allow you to:

1. Programmatically switch between views easily
2. Manage two (or more) separate UIViewController instances in IB easily, without overlapping

Answer (score 0):

For optional / modal parts of a view controller, one approach I've used several times in the past is to create a view for each section as top level objects in the nib.  You can arrange each view using interface builder more easily then, and then all you need to do in your code is conditionally add the appropriate view to the main view in your `viewDidLoad` method.  Remember that, as top-level objects in the nib, they should have strong outlets, not weak outlets.

Comment: How do I edit/view the view in IB when it is a top level object?

Comment: The same way you do with the main view.  The only difference between them is that the main view is hooked up to the view controller's `view` outlet.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, I suggest you put them in a separate nib, and load the views from the nib.  Same basic principle, you just use `UINib` to load them.